# removing from a list in a for loop does not seem to work

Tags: python, list

Example code:

```py
found_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
remove_list =[1,2,3,4,5]

for canidate in found_list:
    if canidate in remove_list:
        found_list.remove(canidate)

# Expecting this to be an EMPTY list. 
# because everything in found is in remove
print("NEW FOUND LIST: %s" % found_list )
```

In my actual case, I am using "os.walk()" - and need to prune/ignore some subdirectories. The example is a list of subdirectories (ie: names like: ".svn" and ".git")  I want to ignore

The examples I have seen are to use for() over the directory or file list.
And use list.remove() to remove the specific item directly.

However - things are not being deleted like I expect.
I think this is a limitation (?bug?) in the way that the for() loop iterates over a list
ie: If you delete the current item the next item is skipped and not considered.

Is this documented anywhere?

My workaround solution is to create a new list and then assign that to the list given by os.walk()

Thanks.

Comment: You could change your loop to loop through the `remove_list` and then remove the element in the `found_list`. That way you're never changing the list that you're iterating over.

Comment: This is a well known mistake - you are modifying a List you are iterating over which compromises the index used to access the List.

Comment: "My workaround solution is to create a new list and then assign that to the list given by os.walk()" so, to be clear, you need something like `dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in (".svn", ".git")]`, where you actually have to mutate the list using slice-assignment if you are working with os.walk IIRC

Answer (score 1):

I re-opened because the question is about where this can be found in the documentation, the asker already understands the mechanism and has found a work-around.

And yes, this is clearly documented.

This is described [here on the documentation of built-in sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range):

> Forward and reversed iterators over mutable sequences access values
> using an index. That index will continue to march forward (or
> backward) even if the underlying sequence is mutated. The iterator
> terminates only when an IndexError or a StopIteration is encountered
> (or when the index drops below zero).

So note, all mutable built-in sequence types will display this behavior:

```
>>> arr = bytearray(b'abcd')
>>> for i in arr:
...     arr.remove(i)
...
>>> arr
bytearray(b'bd')
```